# Unable to set TextView programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to show a list of three separate textviews in my linear layout. I'm aware that this can be done from the XML file itself , but I want to generate these textviews dynamically.

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id = "@+id/ll1">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Java file:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saved){
        LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        super.onCreate(saved);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Negotiation","Pyschology","Joke"));
        for (int i = 0; i<3;++i){
            TextView dynamic = new TextView(this);
            dynamic.setText(names.get(i));
            dynamic.setTextSize(14);
            dynamic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
            });
            ll.addView(dynamic);


        }

    }
}
```

The result is a blank page and what I want is three clickable textviews as the result. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: still seems like a very horrible approach, why not use a recyclerview ?

Comment: I don't see any `yourLinearLayout.addView(yourTextView)` in order to add your generated textview to linear layout.

Comment: I will recommend you to use RecyclerView but if you want to go through this approach add this line yourLinearLayout.addView(dynamic)`
`

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong sir you want to add Text view Programmatically

Find you need a layout parent layout Your parent layout is Linear layout set id of a linear layout Suppose id is linerlayout_parent After this in Activity

```
LinearLayout linearview =  findViewById(R.id.linerlayout_parent);
```

Now Here Create text view Programatically

```
        TextView title=new TextView(Activity.this);
       title.setTextSize(20);
       title.setTextAppearance(context,R.font.abhaya_libre_bold);
       title.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
       title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
       title.setText("Hello use this code");
       linearview.addView(title);
```

if you need three than in Loop paste this code
Kindly set orientation of a Linear layout Vertical

Comment: I did this and I'm getting this error , `"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.kenadams.app.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:39)"`Which happens to be the line `linearview.addView(title)`. I'm also adding an onclicklistener

Comment: Do you use findviewbyid ? make sure you are using id of linearlayout is  same  to the xml id ? is this ok ? than paste you recent code

Comment: I've pasted the new code in my question

Comment: kindly write 
       first this  super.onCreate(saved); than this line  LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.ll1);

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to add textview in parentview like this.

```
  tv[i] = new TextView(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
     ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 50;
params.topMargin  = i*50;
tv[i].setText(str[i]);
tv[i].setTextSize((float) 20);
tv[i].setPadding(20, 50, 20, 50);
tv[i].setLayoutParams(params);
rl.addView(tv[i]);
```